# How can I see scala compilation error on the project tree of intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[image]

As the screenshot shows, I want to see the compilation error in the project tree on the left.

Comment: I guess that it is just not implemented ? For Java sources, you see it. Did you check the Intellij bug tracker?

Comment: I haven't check intellij bug tracker, Yes, for java sources, I can see it. But it doesn't work for scala

Answer (score 0):

This feature is usually active automatically. I searched the [Scala plugin source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala) on GitHub and couldn't find any uses of the class `ProblemFileHighlightFilter` which is the class extended to provide the feature you are talking about, so I think it's possible that they simply don't support it.

This feature is quite simple to add though so you can try reporting/requesting it. Their discussion pages are linked in the GitHub repos readme that I linked above.

Before you do though I would suggest quickly going through `File > Settings` to make sure it isn't just implemented in an unusual way and hiding behind a check box or something.